# Modify ElevateButton just like FlateButton Flutter

Tags: flutter, button

Since **FlateButton** is deprecate in Flutter How to modify **ElevatedButton** just like **Default FlatButton** (Default flat button just look like text)

Comment: the documentation of `FlatButton` tells what to use instead of it

Comment: What you exactly want? please provide a picture of the button you want, or what you had tried but didn't work?

Comment: Use TextButton now,  see the docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Comment: Tha'ts exactly what i want thank you @JorgeVieira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted a simple text button which look like flat button but flat button is deprecated on my sdk.

**Soluton:**

Thank you for the **comments** that help me directly to find my answer.
visit: [click here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons) for the solution.

This solution is working on:
Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable •[github link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git)
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (3 weeks ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Tools • Dart 2.12.3

Comment: Are you sure that in 1 year this URL will still be relevant (after several subsequent releases of SDK)? If not then your answer does not contain any value at all - please include short description of solution here.

Comment: I just edit my answer with short description about the question and  flutter sdk. please check it out @MaximSagaydachny